# Angular 9 - Dynamic Lazy Loading Module - The request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: angular, webpack, lazy-loading

I would leverage [Angular Lazy-loading feature modules](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) to fulfill a pluggable frontend.
So the concept is create extension-points in my app where I can do something like this:

```
import('./customers/customers.component').then(lazyMod => {
   here use lazyMod.CustomersComponent to plug other component's template
})
```

I've developed the idea in a simple PoC in **stackblitz**:
https://angular-9-dynamic-lazy-test.stackblitz.io

**Case 1** - **OK** - Pressing button1 of the PoC, it runs the following code and it's OK:

```
const { HelloComponent } = await import('./hello.component')
```

**Case 2** - **OK** - Pressing button1(bis) of PoC, it runs the following code and it's OK:

```
const helloLazyModulePath = './hello.component'; //component already loaded in case 1
const { HelloComponent } = await import(helloLazyModulePath );
```

**Case 3** - **KO** - Pressing button2 of the PoC, it runs the following code and I get error:

```
const goodbyeLazyModulePath = './goodbye.component';
const { GoodbyeComponent } = await import(goodbyeLazyModulePath);
```

The **error** is: `Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module`.
A build **warning** says: `Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression`

The reason should be this:
According to https://angular.io/guide/deployment#lazy-loading

```
The CLI runs the Angular Ahead-of-Time Webpack Plugin which automatically recognizes
lazy-loaded NgModules and creates separate bundles for them
```

It means that **webpack angular tool**, during the build phase, scans the source-code to find out `@import('path')` and to create a separated bundle for lazy-module.
So if the `@import` is dinamically  used `@import(variable)`, there isn't way for webpack to figure out which feature module must be built in a separated bundle.

I need to use `@import(variable)` because I know which plugin-module to import only during build phase, according to many factors, for example in which environment I'm going to deploy.

Is there a way (a workaround or a compile setup) to use `@import(variable)` without getting error at runtime due to missing separated bundle?

---

EDIT: In addition to the [stackblitz](https://angular-9-dynamic-lazy-test.stackblitz.io) , I pushed the same PoC in this [github repo](https://github.com/fabioformosa/angular-dynamic-lazy-loading)

Answer (score 0):

How dynamic can the path be? I mean you should be able to know all the possible paths. 
So you can just do something like:

```
let componentToUse: Component;

switch (dynamicArg) {
  case 'a': 
    componentToUse = (await import('path/to/a')).ComponentA;
    break;
  ...
}
```

Comment: I've tried, it runs fine but in folder `dist`, after the build, I find all separated-blundles for all lazy modules, also if some of them are not used at runtime. This is a trouble because different lazy modules are developed for different customers and environments. I cannot mix them. Don't hesitate if you have other hints. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @FabioFormosa you can use a different preload strategy so they are not loaded until they are actually needed. This will save the 404s.

Comment: I'm thinking to a fileReplace in angular.json according to environment. What do you mean for preload strategy?

Comment: @FabioFormosa I mean you can tell angular to not eagerly load the lazy modules. This way, if some files are missing on the server (but you never load them) if won't crash on you. https://angular.io/api/router/PreloadingStrategy